# How do I change the default font, site-wide in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla

I'm working with a commercial template: http://templates.entheosweb.com/template_number/30483.asp

My client is French speaking, so the font needs to be able to handle special characters in French, which the current font does not at all. I don't see a straightforward way to change the font inside Joomla's admin section.

Answer (score 1):

The defualt font size for the theme is set in template.css thus

```
body, td, th, div, p, label, input {
color: #535353;
font: normal 13px/17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

So you'd need to alter that. It reads as font weight normal size 13px line height 17px font family Arial.

Once you've changed that search through the remaining styles for font: or font-size and alter those property's values relative to the increased default font size.

Comment: It makes sense that I'd have to change something in the template's CSS. That much I understand. But how will changing font-size help me make sure that the font will display special characters in French? That part I don't get.

In that block of CSS you showed, the font type is set to Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif. That's general enough to allow for the display of special characters... yet it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Oh well that's a different area entirely, language characters like that will only display correctly if you have your page encoding set to utf-8 and correctly tag the french content with a lang attribute. See this http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-fr.htm and this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp. You are relying however on the users computer having an OTF version of Arial that contains these characters - if they are not displaying for you you may need to upgrade your font files.